# Deleting text in EditText using a button

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Does anybody know how to make a button that deletes one character at a time in an EditText?

I tried the following which is a lame attempt really because I don't know how to do it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.keypad_0:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "0");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_1:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "1");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_2:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "2");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_3:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "3");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_4:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "4");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_5:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "5");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_6:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "6");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_7:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "7");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_8:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "8");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_9:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "9");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_minus:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText() + "-");
         break;
     case R.id.keypad_del:
         edittext.setText(edittext.getText().length() - 1); //attempt here
         break;
```

If anybody knows please share

Comment: int length=edittext.getText().toString().length();edittext.setText(edittext.getText(‌​).toString().substring(0,length-1));

Comment: Thanks Samir, that works. Could you explain why? I don't understand why you need a substring to do this

Comment: I think I understand anyway, substring starts at the beginning of the text, length makes it say 2 - 1 = 1. :P Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to remove the last character, the substring method will do nicely:

```
edittext.getText().toString().substring(0, edittext.getText().toString().length()-1);
```

The above code returns the substring of index 0 to the length of the string -1.

Comment: It has to be - 2, doesn't it? The length is 1 based.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, says cannot convert type String to Editable, or vis versa. Its OK though, Samir's answer works like a charm. Thanks anyway Laurence.

Comment: Check out the docs for substring, the above code will produce the requested output.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Comment: Forgot to add toString on getText, sorry. The code snippet should now work!

Comment: No worries, just for reference. The reason you have to use substring is you are wanting to extract a subset of characters from the String returned by edittext.

Your solution "edittext.getText().length() - 1" was half right but would only return the length of the string minus the 1 character. By passing this to substring, a new string is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
edittext.setText(edittext.getText().delete(edittext.length() - 1, edittext.length()));
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me opposed to the other one, thank you.